# Cannot test validation errors in Lumen

Tags: php, phpunit, lumen

When i try to validate controller response using one of the available assertions like `assertJsonValidationErrors` it gives the following error:

```
Failed to find a validation error in the response for key: 'name'
```

Here is my test:

```php
Mesh::factory()->create(['name'=>'test']);
$this->post(route('meshes.store', ['name' => 'test']));
$this->response->assertUnprocessable()->assertJsonValidationErrors('name');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validation response format in Lumen is different than Laravel which wraps the errors in `errors` property.

Simply pass `null` to the second parameter of `assertJsonValidationErrors` or any other methods available for validation assertion which has this parameter and you should be fine:

```
$this->response->assertUnprocessable()->assertJsonValidationErrors('name', null);
```